# Is there a way in Javascript to automatically click the Next button which has no ID's or Class Attributes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, button

I'm attempting to write a command in JavaScript to automatically click the "Next" button. However the problem I'm running into is that the next button doesn't have an ID nor any class attributes. Below is my code any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
<tr>

  <td>

    <input type="Submit" value=" Next >>" onclick="return fnValidate(form);"> == $0

    <script language="JavaScript">

    </script>

  </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also select by attributes.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').click();
```

Note that it will select the very first submit input on the page. So if you have one above you will not match the correct input. Always try to be as precise as possible with you selectors, eg. by selecting a parent element first. Also not that `document.getElementById` is fast than `document.querySelector`. So whenever you can, use an id selector. You can of course ID-Select a parent and then search within it's subtree if you can't modify the subtree for example.

Comment: You're welcome. Always remember to upvote helpful answers and select an answer that solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) by specifying the element's *type* attribute.

**Demo:**

```js
document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').click();

function fnValidate(){
  console.log('button clicked');
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="submit" value=" Next >>" onclick="return fnValidate(form);"> == $0
    <script language="JavaScript">
    </script>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').click();` as suggested by @Mamun

There is one more alternate option as

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input").[0].click();
```

```js
var elm = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].click();

function fnValidate() {
  console.log("Form submitted ")
}
```

```html
<td>

<input type="Submit" value=" Next >>" onclick="return fnValidate(form);"> == $0

<script language="JavaScript">

</script>

</td>

</tr>
```